Node.js - Making an eventEmitter object be common across different scopes
I am new to node.js and javascript but not coding. This is more of a syntax question of "why does this work?" so I can understand the nuances involved
I defined an emitter object in my main.js which I wanted to pass to other modules and functions that would use it to emit or receive events on that event bus
This works fine if I do the following :
const eventEmitter = require('events').EventEmitter;
outputBus = new (eventEmitter)

class methodThing {
    constructor () {}
    
    dothing = function () {
        console.log("function is doing the thing" )
    }
    
    stop = function ()  {
        console.log("function stopped doing the thing")
        
    }
    
}

thing = new methodThing() 



function doathing (outputBus, methodThing) {
 outputBus.emit('start', "Started doing the thing")
   outputBus.on('abort', () => { methodThing.stop()
     methodThing.dothing()
   }
}

doathing(outputBus,thing) 

A emit sent outside of the function is seen inside (if I send an abort from outside the function, the function stops the  methodThing, emits (like the 'start' above from within the function are seen outside.
but if I replace the above line with
outputBus = new eventEmitter()

I never see any events on outputBus  outside of the function or within. The Object seems to acquire its own local scope when passed into the function. The object within the function can see/emit  events on the bus, and   object outside the function can see/emit its own events, but neither sees events from the other.
What I don't understand is why one declaration works ( which I discovered after making a typo) and the other does not.  What is the meaning of putting the object inside () that would cause it to be treated as the same object inside and outside of the function or module it is passed to?  is this a shorthand for declaring it to be public?  (I was trying to avoid doing that)  Am I somehow invoking an inheritance? Is it flat out a bug? I know its a bit of a noob question , but my queries into the documentation are not showing me the answer, probably because I am not using quite the right nomenclature to find it..... If you can provide a deatial answer here that would be awesome, but I have no issue with trying to read and understand the documentation if all you have a time for is a link to the appropriate section.
Many thanks in advance

I'm having a hard time understanding your question.  Are you asking about the difference between outputBus = new (eventEmitter) and outputBus = new eventEmitter()?  And, what do you mean "an emit sent outside"?  Outside of what?  A big red flag here is that outputBus does not seem to be declared anywhere.  Depending upon the code context, that's either an error or creates an implicit global variable.  The same is true of your thing variable.  All variables should be explicitly declared with let or const.

Also, why are you using the syntax: dothing = function () { ...} to define the dothing method? This is public data field syntax and is not the preferred syntax for defining a method for your object.
